# Is it possible to pass a Literal type to a function and have that function output a value of that Literal type?

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I'm trying to write a function for asserting that user input matches a defined Literal type.

Basically, given:

```py
MyLiteral = Literal["foo", "bar"]
```

I want to write a function that lets me do this:

```py
some_user_provided_value = input()   # For example

good_value = assert_literal(MyLiteral, some_user_provided_value)
```

The type of `good_value` should now be inferred to be `MyLiteral`. If the user value didn't match any of the defined literal strings, an assertion error would be raised.

This should have the same effect as:

```py
some_user_provided_value = input()   # For example

good_value: MyLiteral

if some_user_provided_value == "foo":
    good_value = "foo"
elif some_user_provided_value == "bar":
    good_value = "bar"
else:
    raise AssertionError(f"Value {some_user_provided_value!r} is not a MyLiteral")
```

This is a pattern that is often repeated in my project, so I would like to wrap it up in a function.

The function would look something like this:

```py
from typing import Any, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")


def assert_literal(literal_type: T, value: Any) -> T:
    if value not in typing.get_args(literal_type):
        raise AssertionError(f"Value {value!r} is not a {literal_type!r}")

    return typing.cast(T, value)
```

This doesn't work, of course, because this function currently wants an *instance* of type `T` and it'll output an *instance* of type `T`.

If I was dealing with regular classes, I could make the parameter type `Type[T]`, but this explodes in my face when I use Literal types, presumably because `"foo"` is not an *instance* of `MyLiteral`, that doesn't even make any sense.

Is there currently any way to achieve what I'm trying to do? Can `Literals` even be mixed with `TypeVar`s?

Comment: Is it a strong requirement for your use case to use `Literal`? Because you could have this working fairly well with an `Enum` instead.

Comment: @yeoldenoobe I tend to avoid enums in Python, they feel like Java  Literal types are generally so much nicer to use

Comment: @yeoldenoobe I already know enums fit my needs, I just think they are clunky, ugly and less convenient to use  It's an extra import users of my API need to add, and writing `MyEnumType.FOO` is never as intuitive as just `"foo"`.

Comment: You don't have to type `MyEnumType.FOO` if you create your Enum with a `str` mixin. In this case, 'foo' == MyEnumType.FOO`, and users won't have to import it, and even less type it, it will be fully transparent.

Comment: @yeoldenoobe How would that type look in a function signature? What would happen if the user typed a bad string value like `"blorg"`? Would that be caught by type checkers?

Comment: Would look like `Type[Enum]`. Now, I don't know about type checkers, but that is the point of the function you're trying to write, right?

Comment: @yeoldenoobe No, the point of the function I'm trying to write is just user input validation, but the point of the Literal type in general is being able to define strictly typed functions that take regular Python strings as input.

Comment: I thought the question was very interesting and I have run the function as it is. For me it has perfectly work!! passing  ```literal_type=MyLiteral, value="foo" ``` returns me "foo" and ```literal_type=MyLiteral, value="aaa" raise an error. I dont know if I missunderstood the question

Comment: @LucasM.Uriarte Try running mypy on that script :)

Comment: ohhh ok. I get it :) thanks for the tip

Comment: `Literal` is not a type; it's a type *hint*, and a very specific one. It represents actual literals, not a subtype of some other type.

Comment: `mypy` actively refuses to work with literals and `type[...]` together: here's [an issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/5935). `type[Literal[...]]` will be an error at some point.

Answer (score 0):

You can get pretty close using a Generic class, I think.  This solution works with *PyRight* but unfortunately not with [*mypy*](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/1020).

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Generic, Any, TYPE_CHECKING, Literal

T = TypeVar("T")


class LiteralCaster(Generic[T]):
    def __new__(cls, a: Any) -> T:
        # Apply whatever checking logic you want
        return a


MyType = Literal["abc", "def"]
user_input: Any = input()
        
reveal_type(LiteralCaster[MyType](user_input))
```

If you want a mypy-compatible solution, you'll have to go with a much uglier form of this which uses `__call__` instead of `__new__` and requires the converter to be called like this: `LiteralCaster[MyType]()(user_input)`

Answer (score -1):

The wonderful library called [pydantic](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/) offers exactly that.
From their homepage description:

> pydantic enforces type hints at runtime, and provides user friendly errors when data is invalid.

And here's an example for Literal types, found [here](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#literal-type):

```
from typing import Literal

from pydantic import BaseModel, ValidationError


class Pie(BaseModel):
    flavor: Literal['apple', 'pumpkin']


Pie(flavor='apple')
Pie(flavor='pumpkin')
try:
    Pie(flavor='cherry')
except ValidationError as e:
    print(str(e))
    """
    1 validation error for Pie
    flavor
      unexpected value; permitted: 'apple', 'pumpkin'
    (type=value_error.const; given=cherry; permitted=('apple', 'pumpkin'))
    """
```

I would safely rely on this library to do the heavy lifting for you (it is used in the popular FastAPI framework, for example) - but if you want to do it yourself then I'd go to their source code and see how they manage to do that.

Good luck!